# Split an object properties in two columns

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I wanna split an object properties in two columns, when I was using bootstrap I was able to do it with the clearfix class like so:

```
<div class="clearfix" ng-if="$index % 12 == 0"></div>
```

But now I am using angular material and I wanna know how do it. Below fiddle for testing and better explanation:

https://jsfiddle.net/twizzlers/234nLone/1/

```
<div layout="column">
  <span ng-repeat="(key,value) in obj">
    {{key}} : {{value}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following will do what you want

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <span flex=50 ng-repeat="(key,value) in obj">
    {{key}} : {{value}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Always add `flex` to children of `layout`. Getting used to the layout rules/config takes a bit of time

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/234nLone/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you kind Sir, it worked perfectly. Yes, changed from bootstrap cols to angular material layouts and flex, getting used to it =)